# cannot find uploaded image when using Azure Storage Emulator in local machine

Tags: asp.net, azure-blob-storage

asp.net 4.5, Web Forms, vs2013, Identity 2.0, Entity Framework 6.0

I plan to use Azure Storage blob to store user uploaded images. So I downloaded Azure Storage Emulator to test in my local machine.

It seems container is created correctly and image is saved correctly - since I didn't receive any exception when I run the application.

But the problem is that I cannot see this image on my web page. Debugging into the code, I saw this image's URI is

```
http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/my_sub_folder_2/my_image.jpg
```

I paste this url to browser, IE tells me:

```
The webpage cannot be found 404
```

Chrome tells me:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:e4b64fa8-5985-4aa4-bfbe-50aabd497537 Time:2014-04-21T07:26:04.4264011Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

I use AzureStorageAccess.CreateContainer() to create a container in the storage, and use AzureStorageAccess.UploadBlob() to save user uploaded image (stream) to the storage. The code is as follows.

```
public class AzureStorageAccess
{
// create a container in Azure Storage Emulator
    static public void CreateContainer(string containerName)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
            .Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
        // CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

// upload a stream to Azure Storage Emulator
    static public void UploadBlob(System.IO.Stream stream, string containerName, string blobRelativeURI, out string blobURI)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
            .Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
        // CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobRelativeURI);
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
        blobURI = blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
```

I have this connection string in web.config. Initially I was using this connection string. Later when I am trying to solve the problem, I read some posts here in stackoverflow that I should use `Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true")`. You can see the code to read this connection string is commented out in above code.

```
<add key="StorageConnectionString"         value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1"
/>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That is happening because containers by default turn off public read access. You will be able to access the blob from the browser if you change the `Public Read Access` property to `Container` using the `Visual Studio Server Explorer`

[image]

Or if you want to do this in code via the SDK add the following line before you create the container.

```
        //Create container
        container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container });
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have 2 following up questions: (1) I create container in code. It seems you create container by drag-and-drop, how do you do that? (2) I can set permission to public on my test, but when I deploy it to Azure, how can I guarantee that those images are only accessible by authorized user?

Comment: 1) I am doing this using the Server Explorer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk.aspx.

Comment: 2) Can you set the permission to BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container only when you use the development storage? By default the permission is set to BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off.

Comment: Hey, just a question from due to VS 2019. Do you know how to open the emulated storage in VS 2019 in the "Server Explorer". I don't get it..I can only open it in the Cloud Explorer and there is no option to change the "Public Read Access"....

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it is directly trough Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.
Right click on your blob container and select Set Public Access Level...

[Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0V3l.png)

Answer (score 0):

On create set public access:

```cs
public async ValueTask<bool> CreateContainer(string name)
{
    try {
        await _blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(name, PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
        return true;
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```