# How to use Azure storage emulator blob endpoint to get a blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

The following code, when pointed to a real Azure storage account will successfully return the blob content:

```
var path = $"{container}/{blob}";
var rfcDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
var headers =  "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" +
               "x-ms-blob-type:Block\n" +
              $"x-ms-date:{rfcDate}\n" + 
              $"x-ms-version:{ServiceVersion}\n" +
              $"/{AccountName}/{path}";
var uri = new Uri(BlobEndpoint + path);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "Block");
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", rfcDate);
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", ServiceVersion);

string signature = "";
using (var sha = new HMACSHA256(System.Convert.FromBase64String(AccountKey)))
{
  var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headers);
  signature = System.Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(data));
}

var authHeader = $"SharedKey {AccountName}:{signature}";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
  return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

However, if I configure it to use the Azure emulator where:

- **AccountName** = devstoreaccount1
- **AccountKey** = Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==
- **BlobEndpoint** = http://127.0.0.1:10000/
- **ServiceVersion** = 2009-09-19

I always get 404. I'm using Azure Storage Emulator v4.6. Is the code or config incorrect or is this not supported with the emulator?

Comment: Duplicated, correct response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193060/cannot-find-uploaded-image-when-using-azure-storage-emulator-in-local-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Blob Service in Storage Emulator listens at `http://127.0.0.1:1000` however the base URI is `http://127.0.0.1:1000/devstoreaccount1`.
2. In computation of `Signature String` (`header` variable in your code), account name must appear twice. This is because the account name is part of your resource's URI path (URL for the blob would be `http://127.0.0.1:1000/devstoreaccount1/container-name/blob-name`).

Based on these, please try the following code:

```
    static async Task<string> ReadBlobFromDevStorage()
    {
        var container = "temp";
        var blob = "test.txt";
        var ServiceVersion = "2009-09-19";
        var AccountName = "devstoreaccount1";
        var BlobEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1";
        var path = $"{container}/{blob}";
        var AccountKey = "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==";
        var rfcDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
        var headers = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" +
                       "x-ms-blob-type:Block\n" +
                      $"x-ms-date:{rfcDate}\n" +
                      $"x-ms-version:{ServiceVersion}\n" +
                      $"/{AccountName}/{AccountName}/{path}";
        var uri = new Uri(BlobEndpoint + "/" + path);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "Block");
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", rfcDate);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", ServiceVersion);

        string signature = "";
        using (var sha = new HMACSHA256(System.Convert.FromBase64String(AccountKey)))
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headers);
            signature = System.Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(data));
        }

        var authHeader = $"SharedKey {AccountName}:{signature}";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            return content;
        }
    }
```